# How to convert string to object in javascript？

Tags: javascript, string, object

```
const str="{a:{url:'http://localhost:80',c:1,},d:'d',e:true}"
```

How to get the result without using evil and new Function:

```
const obj={a:{url:'http://localhost:80',c:1,},d:'d',e:true}
```

Comment: Suggestion: make whatever is generating `str` produce valid JSON, rather than a random format. Then parse it as JSON.

Comment: Well your choice is `eval`/`new Function` or altering the string so it is valid JSON OR building a parser

Comment: @SudhirOjha the string in this question is not valid JSON. Parsing it won't help.

Comment: That's right. JSON is not valid

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

You need to format your string into a valid JSON format ( double quotes instead of single quotes )

And then you'll just need to `JSON.parse(str)`

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to json you can use `JSON.parse(str)` 
But first make sure the string syntax is correct, there are several websites to do this, one of many is this https://jsonlint.com/